# Populate Grails g:select from function

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Trying to populate a g:select from a function in my controller, is it possible?

Currently we have this:

```
def run(Long id) {

    def reportInstance = Report.get(id)

    def listPromptValues = populatePrompts(reportInstance)*.values()

    if (!reportInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'report.label', default: 'Report'), id])            
        return
    }
    [reportInstance: reportInstance, listPromptValues: listPromptValues]
}

def populatePrompts(Report rp){
    //for each prompt in the report, go out and get it's values
    rp.prompts.collectMany {
        reportService.listDatatypeValues(it.datatype)
    }

}
```

And then the g:select in question is

```
<li class="fieldcontain">
                <g:each var="prompt" in="${reportInstance.prompts}">
                    <span id="prompts-label" class="property-label">
                        <g:message code="report.prompts.label" default="${prompt.name}:" />
                    </span>
                    <g:if test="${prompt.datatype.type == 'DropDown'}">                         
                        <g:select id="prompt.name" from="${listPromptValues}" name="prompt.name" value="" noSelection="['':'']"/>
                        <br>                            
                    </g:if>
                </g:each>
            </li>
```

Which works just fine if there is only one prompt, however we need to be able to call the populatePrompt function directly from the gsp view if there is more than one prompt in the loop, possible sending the reportId and then getting back the listPromptValues. I can't seem to get the onChange(remoteFunction...) to work properly and am coming up empty handed in searching the vast Google webs.

Something like how createLink works

```
${createLink(controller:'report', action:'runReport', id:"${reportInstance.id}")}
```

But instead of createLink, it would be the from attribute of the select tag, something like:

```
<g:select id="prompt.name" from="{(controller:'report',action:'populatePrompt', id:"${reportInstance.id}")}" name="prompt.name" value="" noSelection="['':'']"/>
```

Any ideas, or direction to go?

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question, probably because your data makes no sense to me.

Comment: Ok @JamesKleeh. We have a report object, which in turn has prompts. The prompts are values stored in a database, and I need to populate them on the UI via the controller. The prompts could have different values, say one would be a year selection, and another month. How would I populate the g:select with that data?

Comment: The listPromptValues are already being sent down to the view. The current g:select works correct? What other data needs to be in there?

Comment: Say there are two prompts for this report, when run is called in the controller it is going to return listPromptValues with both prompt's values in one big list. I need to get back 2 lists, or n lists based on the number of prompts. Each prompts should get it's own list of values back from the controller.

Comment: You can send down a map that has all of that data, you dont need to do  it with ajax. ex `[prompt1: ['a','b','c'], prompt2: ['d','e','f']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @JamesKleeh proposed a viable solution in his last comment.

Given the fact that your gsp structure is quite static, it doesn't make sense to fetch the prompt select options to be dynamically loaded. Just return these options in a List package within `listPromptValues` from your controller and take it in the gsp directly.

Concerning your parameters like `[prompt1: ['a','b','c'], prompt2: ['d','e','f']]`, you can get this map in your `populatePrompts` method and put each key-value pair into gsp select tags. Like this:

**controller**

```
{    ....
    def listPromptValues = populatePrompts(reportInstance)
    ....
}

def populatePrompts(Report rp){
    //for each prompt in the report, go out and get it's values
    def promptMap = [:]            //map to be returned
    rp.prompts.each {
        promptMap.put(it.name, reportService.listDatatypeValues(it.datatype))
    }
    return promptMap
}
```

**gsp**

```
                <g:each var="prompt" in="${reportInstance.prompts}">
                    <span id="prompts-label" class="property-label">
                        <g:message code="report.prompts.label" default="${prompt.name}:" />
                    </span>
                    <g:if test="${prompt.datatype.type == 'DropDown'}">                         
                        <g:select id="prompt.name" from="${listPromptValues[prompt.name]}" name="prompt.name" value="" noSelection="['':'']"/>
                        <br>                            
                    </g:if>
                </g:each>
```

Comment: I would agree that the page is very static. Ideally there should be only one call to the controller when the end user selects a report, and that call would return all the list values. How would i go about this? I can't find any references on how to build a list package from the controller, and then parse the data from within the gsp page. Thanks

Comment: @Idonaldson That is something basic of Grails. You can find a bunch of examples in Grails Docs. Essentially it is about sending embedded Lists from controller and rendering them in gsp view. <g:each> is useful in this scenario.

Comment: I get the <g:each>, and how they work the embedded lists are where I am lacking. Thanks @Jinzhao for reaffirming that I don't know Grails. More specifically how do I build the map [prompt1: ['a','b','c'], prompt2: ['d','e','f']]

Comment: @idonaldson I updated my code. I'm not sure about your domain definition, so it's just a example. If you can not get it right, show me your domain classes.

Comment: THANK YOU! That definitely got me a lot closer to where I need to be. Now I just need to figure out how to strip the values back out of the map. I had it as def listPromptValues = populatePrompts(reportInstance)*.values(), but that throws an error now. So I moved the *.values() into the gsp and it seems to return the list of values. Any thoughts on removing the map brackets[]? Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: Glad to see it works. Just use `listPromptValues = populatePrompts(reportInstance)` and don't move `*.values()` into gsp. `from = ` in `<g:select>` should be a list value, so `${listPromptValues[prompt.name]}` as ['a','b','c'] is just fine for that.

Comment: It isn't though `listPromptValues = polulatePrompts(reportInstance)` returns 2 key:value pairs. Such as `[TERM_CODE=201360,TERM_DESC=Autumn 2013]`. I just need `201360: Autumn 2013` and adding `*.values()` gets me pretty close. Just need to strip the leading `[` and trailing `]` and we'd be golden.

Comment: @idonaldson I'm confused on your data structure. Do you want some values from different properties to be joined with ':' to form a string? What does it mean to <g:select>?

Comment: These are values coming straight from our DB. It is a simple select statement that grabs a term code, followed by a useful description.

Comment: @idonaldson I don't quite clear about it, but if you really want to do like that,  `listPromptValues = polulatePrompts(reportInstance).collect{it.value}` will return a list for you, and `listPromptValues = polulatePrompts(reportInstance).collect{it.value}.join(' ')` will produce a String.